# The slider in cypress invokes the changes , but the changes are not captured in the textbox

Tags: slider, cypress

The assertion to verify the selected value from the slider input fails, while the script runs, the slider position changes correctly but it doesn't take any effect on the textbox; the value in the box isn't updated.

```js
describe('Validate the slidervalue', function() {

  it('Should assert the slider value correctly', function() {
    cy.visit('https://demoqa.com/slider')
    cy.get('input[type="range"]').invoke('val', 65).trigger('change')
    cy.get('#sliderValue').should('have.value', 65)

  })
})
```

Comment: The assertion to verify the selected value from the lider input fails, while the script runs , the lider position changes corrrec tly but it doesnt take any effect on the textbox ; the value in the b ox isnt updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't figured out the problem with `val()` but `stepup()` works

```js
it('Should assert the slider value correctly', function() {
  cy.visit('https://demoqa.com/slider')
  cy.get('input[type="range"]')
    .then($el => $el[0].stepUp(40) )  // steps = 65 - 25
    .trigger('change')
  cy.get('#sliderValue').should('have.value', 65)     // passes
})
```

---

Or with helper function

```js
const stepTo = ($el, target) => {
  const step = $el[0].getAttribute('step') || 1
  const current = $el[0].value
  const diff = target - current
  const steps = Math.abs(diff * step)
  if (diff > 0) {
    $el[0].stepUp(steps)
  else {
    $el[0].stepDown(steps)
  }
}

it('Should assert the slider value correctly', function() {
  cy.visit('https://demoqa.com/slider')
  cy.get('input[type="range"]')
    .then($el => stepTo($el, 65) )  
    .trigger('change')
  cy.get('#sliderValue').should('have.value', 65)     // passes
})
```

Comment: So , I understand , we have to script the difference ( 65-25) depending upon what value we are looking to set with the slider; in this case 65 . Had it been 40 then , .stepUP(15) shlould be scripted. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes that's correct. I added a helper function that does the calculation.

Comment: Works perfectly. You're the boss!

Answer (score 1):

I found that when using `cy.get(selector).invoke("val", newVal).trigger(event)` I had to trigger `input` rather than `change`. The [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger#Interact-with-a-range-input-slider) also note that `input` may be required for some implementations.

For the example in the question this would use:

```
  cy.get('input[type="range"]').invoke('val', 65).trigger('input')
```